# Why can I change array elements in a foreach(), but not list elements?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] arr = new int[5]{ 1,2,3,4,5};
        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};
        foreach(int i in arr)
        {
            arr[2] = 7;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            list[2] = 7;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Using `foreach()` on a collection will get an enumerator and repeatedly call `MoveNext()`.

In the case of an array, I can change items in the collection while iterating over it.

However, the code iterating over the `List<T>` throws an exception after the first loop:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Why is it allowed for arrays, but not for a `List<T>`?

Comment: In your first loop, you're modifying `list`, not `arr` - did you intend to?

Answer (score 2):

A `List<T>` keeps a `version` variable that changes with each modification. Adding, removing or changing items in a list increase the version.

When a list's enumerator is created, it is bound to the verison of the list at that time. Each time when you call `MoveNext()` (or: with each `foreach()` iteration), this version is checked against the original list. When the version differs, the given exception is thrown.

The ArrayEnumerator doesn't have such a check, as an array doesn't really have a version field. However, [MSDN mentions at `Array.GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and **its behavior is undefined**.

So while your first example seems to be working, it isn't guaranteed to.